# If I can easily fetch records by join of two tables. Then why we need relationship between tables

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql relationships. I have a very simple question:

Why do we need relationships between tables, if we can easily fetch records by a join of two tables?

for example: I have two tables; one is user and the second one is images. Below are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)



CREATE TABLE images(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT ,
    path varchar(100) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I can easily fetch records from these two tabels with the help join like :-

```
Select * from users as u left join images as im on u.id=im.user_id
```

> **So my simple question is that why we need database relationship between these two tables . Expect this thing that relationship provide delete or update functionality like if we update or delete parent then its child automatically updated or deleted ?**

Thanks in advance for everyone.

Comment: I dunno... Data integrity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints are there to help you maintain the correctness (integrity) of the data - they'll help prevent inserting illegal data (e.g., in your case, an image without a user). The `on delete` and `on update` clauses make the database's maintenance easier, so you don't have to handle all the tables, and can just focus on the "main" table and leave the heavy lifting to the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason is for validating the value. With foreign key, we can confident that while inserting a new Image record, the user_id exist in the user table.